# Setting a property's property during initalization of an object (ClientCredentials) using shorthand-style?

Tags: c#

I'm used to the syntax below when returning simple objects. It's easier, shorter, cleaner and neater.

```
return Stuff{ Prop1 = "a", Prop2 = 5 };
```

However, for some reason, I can't instantiate `ClientCredentials` the same way. I want to specify `UserName` property but intellisense just gives me a huge list of confusing stuff that I'm not sure what to do with. And the property I'm looking for isn't there. I thought that syntax was recommended and standard... What gives?

EDIT:

I'd like to use the syntax:

```
return ClientCredentials
{ 
  UserName.Password = "abc123",
  UserName.UserName = "server\\user"
};
```

instead of:

```
ClientCredentials clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "server\\user";
clientCredentials.UserName.Password = "abc123";
return clientCredentials;
```

Comment: Can you show more code of what you are trying to do / accomplish?

Comment: `return ClientCredentials{ UserName = };`

Comment: Thanks for the reformat. I saw it myself too so I changed it simultaneously with you. Should've looked at the preview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See MSDN article here [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.clientcredentials.username.aspx)

It says that UserName property is a [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.usernamepasswordclientcredential.aspx) with only a get accessor. There is also an example how to set its' values - you cant do this with initialzer

EDIT: after OP comment:
you can't set property's properties in initializer, you'll have to do it the old way

Comment: I meant to set the `UserName` property **in** the `UserName` object (i know, it's confusingly named)...

Comment: You can't set property's properties in initializer, you'll have to do it the old way

Comment: Darn... The answer I did fear but didn't want to hear... Set it as an answer (preferably with a link to something informative) so I can check you green.

Comment: I prefer anyway to not run through initializers like that and instead of have dedicated factory methods and/or constructors that explicitly require and handle them. In your example above, you'd be duplicating the username/password assignments everywhere you create a `ClientCredentials` object, be dependent on their `UserName` property, and remember to assign _both_ username _and_ password if both are required. By placing those as string input parameters in a constructor/factory method, then all of that goes away. EDIT: any subsequent refactoring, usage finding, etc is very easy too.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the `UserName` property of the `ClientCredentials.UserName` property which makes it somewhat confusing. However, it is easy to encapsulate this into a method:

```
ClientCredentials CreateClientCredentials(String userName, String password) {
  var clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials();
  clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
  clientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
  return clientCredentials;
}
```

This syntax is not something you can change. The `ClientCredentials` class and associated types were designed like this.

If you really want to "modify" the syntax one option is create a fluent API using extensions methods which in some situations allows you to create small embedded DSL's in your code. For this particular case I don't think there is a good solution but as an inspiration I provide here some extension methods:

```
public static class ClientCredentialsExtensions {

  public static ClientCredentials WithUserName(
    this ClientCredentials clientCredentials, String userName) {
    // Argument checking omitted.
    clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
    return clientCredentials;
  }

  public static ClientCredentials WithPassword(
    this ClientCredentials clientCredentials, String password) {
    // Argument checking omitted.
    clientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
    return clientCredentials;
  }

}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
var clientCredentials = new ClientCredentials()
  .WithUserName("username")
  .WithPassword("password");
```

However, I don't think it is any better than this:

```
var clientCredentials = new CreateClientCredentials("username", "password");
```

Comment: That's what I posted in my question. My issue is that I'd prefer the compact instant-create-and-init-style.